# Unchecked cast from X to generic type that extends X

Tags: java, java-8, casting, unchecked-cast, unchecked-conversion

I've been tasked with removing as many `@SupressWarning`s as possible in our codebase, and I'm not sure how to get around this particular issue.

I have this external method that returns a `Serializable` object, and a generic type `T extends Serializable` that I would like to cast the object to.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```java
class A <T extends Serializable> {

    public T someMethod() {
        Serializable result = someExternalMethod(...);
        T convertedObject = (T) result; // produces unchecked cast warning

        return convertedObject;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to perform this conversion without producing an unchecked cast warning (assuming the external method cannot be changed)?

This is **Java 8**.

Comment: Can you change the method so that it accepts a `Class<T>`? It will then be easy to actually do the checking. As it stands, the warning is right on the money - you have no way of knowing that the method returns the correct object type.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes that is a possibility, and that would fix my issue. I will hold out for other solutions though, as your solution would involve some tricky refactoring.

Comment: Are you sure that `(T) result` is a conform cast in your case?

Comment: @dehasi I don't know what you mean by _conform cast_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend the answer of [ferpel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7564756/ferpel) you can pass the type as a parameter

```
    class A <T extends Serializable> {

        public T someMethod(Class<T> type) {
            Serializable result = someExternalMethod(...);
            return type.cast(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or for greater generality: `public <C extends T> T someMethod(Class<C> type)` if the caller knows that the result is a subtype of `T` and prefers to pass that subtype. It only removes the warning, of course: A `ClassCastException` will happen if `someExternalMethod` doesn’t return the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the line that produces unchecked cast warning with

```
T convertedObject = anyClassYouWant.cast(result);
```